# Save ssh -V to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

I am trying to automate the testing of passwordless ssh from 72 remote servers back to a central server.   I have central server passwordless ssh working to the 72 servers, but need it working from them back the the central server.

The 72 servers have one of two ssh versions.

> OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

OR

> sshg3: SSH Tectia Client 6.1.8 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
>  Build: 136 
>  Product: SSH Tectia Client License 
>  type: commercial

The issue I am experience is trying to save **ssh -V** into a variable, it seems that it does not print to STDOUT. Thus my attempts below are failing.

```
ssh -V > someFile.txt
ssh_version=$(ssh -V)
```

How can I easily save output of **ssh -V** so that the appropriate ssh batch option can be called?

Below is the script I am using for remote testing.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -V > /tmp/ssh_version_check.txt

cat /tmp/ssh_version_check.txt | grep "OpenSSH"
rc=$?

if [[ $rc == 0 ]]
then
    ssh -o BatchMode=yes <central_server> "test -d /tmp"
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc != 0 ]]
    then
            echo "$(hostname) failed" >> /tmp/failed_ssh_test.txt
    fi
else
    ssh -B <central_server> "test -d /tmp"
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc != 0 ]]
    then
            echo "$(hostname) failed" >> /tmp/failed_ssh_test.txt
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh -V` outputs to `STDERR`, not `STDOUT`.

Instead of saying

```
ssh -V > /tmp/ssh_version_check.txt
```

say

```
ssh -V >& /tmp/ssh_version_check.txt
```

or

```
ssh -V > /tmp/ssh_version_check.txt 2>&1
```

---

In order to save to a variable, say:

```
ssh_version=$(ssh -V 2>&1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this corrected the issue.  I now feel silly for not even trying STDERR from the get go.

Follow-up: What benefit does printing to STDERR provide over STDOUT?

Comment: @BrandonC Programs usually write error message to `STDERR` and output to `STDOUT`.  It's not quite evident why the authors chose to write the version information for `ssh` to `STDERR`.